# Why is the coordinate system in sprite kit flipped and can I change that globally?

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode

I noticed that in Sprite Kit the coordinate system is flipped.

For example, here is a SKSpriteNode:

```
SKSpriteNode *car = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"car"];
car.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
[road addChild:car];
```

The car is positioned in the center of it's parent.

When I set position to:

```
car.position = CGPointMake(-50, 0);
```

then it is positioned more to the left.
But when I want to move it down, and increase Y, it moves UP!

```
car.position = CGPointMake(-50, 20);
```

In UIKit increasing Y always means something moves down. It feels more logical to me. Is there a way to flip the coordinate system in Sprite Kit?

Comment: Don't fight it, embrace it. This is the standard OpenGL coordinate system.

Comment: Well this is going to confused the hell out of me...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set your scene's `yScale` property to -1. Everything will render upside down, but you can also set the `yScale` property for each node to -1, which will cause them to render right side up.

You could also make a class category and create a property called `invertedPosition` with a custom getter/setter that inverts the default `position` property.

Answer (score 0):

Sprite Kit uses a coordinate orientation that starts from the bottom left corner of the scene (0,0), and the values increase as you move to the right (increasing x) and up (increasing y).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of "can I change that"