# SpriteKit/SKScene: How to draw from top-left instead from bottom-left?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

As we know `SKScene`'s origin is at bottom-left.

But i try a simple level loading from a file which contains a matrix of 0 and 1. While 0 is nothing, 1 means a wall (simple rectangle).

As the content of the file obviously goes from top-left to bottom-right, i would like to draw from top-left on the scene.

But my first character from file is drawn on bottom-left on the scene.
I tried setting the scene's **yScale** to -1 hoping its inverting the y-axis, **but that didn't work**.

What is the cleanest way so on this `SKScene` i always start drawing from top-left? I still want to keep my `anchorPoint` at 0.5,0.5.

So drawing from top-left would be located at `x=-widthOfScreen/2` and `y=heightOfScreen/2`

Comment: Take a look to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20734093/1894067

Comment: nope, as i wrote yScale on SKScene does not work. Getting msg on console: SKScene: Setting the scale of a SKScene has no effect.

Comment: Interesting but without see your code i think guys in answer cannot better understand how to help you, try to add some code to reply this issue

Comment: You can use an intermediate node that has a yScale of -1 to achieve this, but if you want your drawings to match the coordinate system of everything else in your scene, your best bet is to just draw your walls in the negative direction instead of the positive direction and not try to transform everything.  It would keep things simpler in the long run, I'd wager, because it's probably a single minus sign somewhere in your level loading code compared to having to deal with an extra layer of transformations throughout your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're going for, but if you just want to change the coordinate system around what you can do is create an extension for CGPoint, something like

```
//CGPoint+SpriteKit.swift
extension CGPoint {
    func flipCoordinates() -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: x, y: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - y)
    }
}
```

I *think* this should work, since your anchor point is (0.5, 0.5)

Comment: Not exactly what i did, but i simply flipped the Y coord when drawing the tiles (level) and elements. Everything else i keep drawing the usual way, since anchorpoint is at 0.5,0.5. But flipping at one point instead of transforming everything is the easiest way to go. Thanks.

Comment: great solution,I spent my 1 day to know why my line display on top while draw at bottom & when draw at top it display at bottom with same space from screen edges...it helps me to solve SKScene issue

Comment: Wanted to translate SCNView coordinates to SKView! and this works perfectly!! Thank you Hayden, spend more than an hour trying to do this cause I stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Since SKSpriteNode will let you flip its content using a scale of -1, you can place all your nodes under a master SKSpriteNode with a yScale of -1.

```
 final class GameScene: SKScene 
 {    
     var masterNode:SKSpriteNode! = nil
     override func addChild(node: SKNode) 
     {
        if masterNode == nil
        { 
           masterNode = SKSpriteNode()
           masterNode.position    = CGPoint(x:0, y:size.height)
           masterNode.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
           masterNode.yScale      = -1
           super.addChild(masterNode)        
        } 
        masterNode.addChild(node)
     }
 }
```

Note that you will need to keep the masterNode's y position aligned with the view size if/when the size changes.

Comment: Why using dynamic dispatch to the GameScene? It's a restriction on a class, is there a valid reason?

Comment: Any idea why we can't do this directly to the `SKScene`? I tried it and it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Alain T's answer but instead using a `SKCameraNode` with `yScale = -1` so you don't need to override the `addChild` function or have an extra node layer.

```
let localCamera = SKCameraNode()
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    super.didMove(to: view)

    localCamera.yScale = -1
    localCamera.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
    addChild(localCamera)
    self.camera = localCamera
// ...
}
```